# Проблема с извлечением цен в разной валюте из текста

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст со списками цен. Извлечь из него цены в USD, RUR, EU.
Примеры правильных выражений: `23.78 USD`.
Примеры неправильных выражений: `22 UDD, 0.002 USD`.

Проблема в том,что я не могу отфильтровать выражения типа `0.002 USD`, вопрос как это сделать? Код программы:

```
import re 
text = input("Введите список цен в USD,RUR,EU:")
d = re.findall(r'(?:(?:([1-9]+[.][1-9]+[USD]{3})|([1-9]+[.][1-9]+[RUR]{3})|([1-9]+[.][1-9]+[EU]{2}))|(?:([1-9]+[USD]{3})|([1-9]+[RUR]{3})|([1-9]+[EU]{2})))',text)
print(d)
```

Comment: можете привести несколько примеров ввода пользователя?

Comment: Введите списки цен в EU,RUR,USD:23.89 USD 0.002 USD 0.3 UDD

Comment: вывод 23.89 USD

Comment: Введите списки цен в EU,RUR,USD:89.78 USD 1.111 EU

Comment: вывод:89.78 USD 1.111 EU

Comment: можете пояснить почему `0.002 USD` - неправильный ввод, а `1.111 EU` - правильный? Является ли целое число: `123 USD` правильным вводом? И как быть с `1.5 USD`?

Comment: Извините,но нет(...но я поставлю вам галочку

Comment: Дело не в галочке... Вы можете точно сформулировать вопрос?

Comment: да,123 USD правильным вводом является

Comment: На данный момент я не могу сформулировать точный вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86825/discussion-between-noob-prog-and-maxu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное решение будет искать целые и десятичные числа с одним или двумя знаками после запятой, после числа должен присутствовать код валюты - один из `USD`, `EU`, `RUR`:

```
In [48]: pat = r'(?:^|[\n\r]|[^\w\d\.])([1-9]\d*(?:.\d{,2})?\s*(?:USD|EU|RUR))\b'

In [49]: re.findall(pat, '89.78 USD 1.111 EU')
Out[49]: ['89.78 USD']

In [50]: re.findall(pat, 'blah 23.78 USD, 22 UDD, 0.002 RUR 123 EU, 123.45 RUR, 1.111 USD')
Out[50]: ['23.78 USD', '123 EU', '123.45 RUR']

In [51]: re.findall(pat, '23.89 USD 0.002 USD 0.3 UDD')
Out[51]: ['23.89 USD']

In [52]: re.findall(pat, '23.89 USD 0.002 USD 0.3 UDD 1.5 RUR')
Out[52]: ['23.89 USD', '1.5 RUR']
```

---

Из комментариев выяснилось, что `1.111 EU` - правильный ввод. Логику почему  `0.002 USD` является неправильны вводом, а `1.111 EU` - правильным я понять не могу. Поэтому в данном решенинии все десятичные числа, у которых дробная часть состоит из более чем двух цифр - считаются неправильным вводом пользователя.

Comment: Max U,объясните пожалуйста зачем нужен символ \w если нас удовлетворяет \d?

Comment: при вводе ipyu89.90 USD список остаётся пустой